# How to create a dynamically updated floating table

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

In Excel I'm able to create a floating image which references a set of data and updates dynamically, which effectively creates a dynamically updating floating table. (See https://superuser.com/questions/547564/how-can-i-create-a-floating-text-box-in-excel-that-contains-data-from-a-workshee)

However, I can't seem to figure out how to do this in Google Sheets. Is there a way that I'm just missing?

Second totally unrelated question: In Google Sheets, is there a way to create one sheet, and then duplicate it but have all of the duplicates update with any changes made to the original sheet?

Ultimately, I need to have multiple sheets all formatted identically but with different data entered into each. I'd like to make it so that, should I need to make any changes, like adding a column or something, I can do it to the original sheet and all of the ones referencing it follow suit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure about a dynamic image, however you could have a dynamically updating data set by using the Query function. As you update data, it will automatically update based on how you'd like to display the information. I suppose you could always just have one browser window that was open with this information in it.

[Google Query Function Documentation](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1BV94ZVI1b1AkM0xOx503mfo01Yj9CVtdFXdQZzelGNk/edit)

The importrange function would allow you to keep one sheet as your source of truth, and then import that sheet into multiple others.

[Import Range Documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en)

You can even take it one step further and imbed a importrange function within a query function. I'll provide you an example:

```
=query(importrange("spreadsheetGUID","range!A:Z"),"select * where Col1 is not null")
```

> *If this doesn't work for you right out of the gate: 
> A) Make sure you
>   have edit permissions for both sheets you're referencing. 
> B) Try to put just
>   the importrange function into the cell first, then grant permission
>   for the sheet you're working in to access the sheet you're trying to
>   reference.
> C) Make sure you have the right GUID in your import range call. It's located in the URL between `...spreadsheets/d/` and `.../edit#gid=...`*

The above query would import from the sheet data referenced in the importrange function, and then you can perform your filtering using where clauses. NOTE: You must interpret the column letters into column numbers. If your range went from B:D in your sheet, the mapping would be like so:

> `B` => `Col1`
>   `C` => `Col2`
>   `D` => `Col3`

Note that `Col1` is also case sensitive, so `col1` or `COL1` would not work.

Another REALLY cool thing, is that you can even nest query functions in query functions using these column references. Here is an example of that (PS - this is a real example I harvested from a sheet I use):

```
=query(query(AA:AZ,"select AQ,count(AM) group by AQ order by count(AM) DESC limit 1"),"select Col2 label Col2 ''"))
```

Here, I'm getting the name (`AQ`) with the highest record count (`count(AM)`) in my data set (EG: John, 5). I only needed the count, but I had to group it with a name so I could get an accurate breakdown by name to get the top result. To slice the name off, I simply queried my query to get only the second column from my data set, which was the count of the name (`AM`). Then I labeled it using `label Col2 ''`, so that the result only took one cell rather than 2 (1 for the cell label, one for the data result).

There is more, but I'll stop here. Seriously, if you learn the query function + importrange your spreadsheet game will jump TREMENDOUSLY! Have fun! :)

Comment: This looks pretty powerful. I'll have to really delve into it when I get back to work. This is great, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome - good luck! Let me know it works for you, and if you want to share an example sheet I can try to help you out.